# Is thermal transfer in a vacuum proportional to temperature difference?

Tags: thermal-radiation, thermal-conductivity

I would have thought that heat dissipation was proportional to temperature difference, especially in a vacuum. Is this true?

Comment: Suppose both surfaces are black, the cold one absorbs everything and the hot one radiates - then clearly it is not the temperature difference what governs heat transport but the hot surface temperature to the fourth power.

Comment: Thanks, I was kind of thinking that.  I've gotten no answers yet so I'm going to try to answer this myself.

Answer (score 3):

Conductive heat transfer is indeed linear.

However black-body radiation follows the [Stefan-Boltzmann Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_law) which states that the heat emission due to black-body radiation is proportional to the 4th power of temperature.  Of course if both surfaces are at the same temperature then no net heat transfer occurs.  Heat transfer is proportional to the difference of the temperatures to the power of 4.  This means that it's not just the difference in temperature, but amplified by the sum of their temperatures and the sum of the square of their temperatures.

$T_1^4 - T_2^4= (T_1 - T_2)(T_1 + T_2)(T_1^2 + T_2^2)$

Thus heat transfer in a vacuum is partially proportional (conductive), and partially non linear.

Convection losses are highly non-linear, but not applicable in a vacuum.

Comment: Before we can discuss this answer we should see an expression for the heat flux, with the right units and proper accounting for geometric factors.

Comment: The question was to be about proportions.  I was taking the approach that conversion to heat flux is a constant conversion factor (with units).  Likewise, does the geometry change the proportionality with respect to $T_1^4-T_2^4$?

Comment: Suppose object A is a small sphere and object B is a large spherical shell surrounding the first object. Then B gets all of the radiated energy from A, but A only get half of B's (with the other half being radiated away into the vacuum from the outer surface). Now you have something like $T_A^4 - T_B^4/2$. So yes, geometry matters.

Comment: @Michael you may confirm from the same Wikipedia page that the power radiated is proportional to $A T^4$, where a is the surface area. Hence area matter, and total radiated energy also depends of time, since we are talking about power here.